# Missing icon for one drive?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, icons

I turned on my PC today and found this:

[image: Icon]

This is the only icon which is messed up. It also shows this way in Media Player and Firefox.

I've already tried rebuilding the icon cache by different methods like using Powershell script, manually deleting 'IconCache.db', emptying recycle bin and using cmd to delete it. I also rebooted the PC after all attempts.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you boot to a minimal configuration?

Comment: Sounds like yet another Windows anomaly. Is there any autorun.ini inside there that might affect the actual icon of the drive?

Comment: No, there's not an autorun inside this path.

Comment: What do you exactly mean, Ramhound? I didn't understand, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the issue has gone after reboot.

Meanwhile, run SFC /SCANNOW command to scan and fix the whole system files.

Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files

If the issue persists, you may need to backup all data in that drive and then delete this drive and re-create it.